# 12th vs 21st century archers in a battle to death, who would survive?

Tags: medieval

(Hey there, newcomer here. If the following question isn't suited for worldbuilding, please let me know!)

So, I have the following situation:

There is a untouched, natural forest shaped as a circle with a diameter of a mile with some kind of invisible barrier around it. This is set in late spring / early summer with a temperature of 20°C.
The forest contains everything a hunter could want to survive. Water sources, fire inflictint material and everything you can think of, that could be found in the nature.
The forest contains normal wildlife. Rabbits, foxes, deer and so on.

In this forest are 100 equipped archers.
50 of them from the ~12th century, the other 50 coming from nowadays.
All persons have the best archer equipment available at their time, but no other weapons besides a bow and some kind of dagger, which could be used for skinning animals and stuff like this.

All of the 12th century guys perfectly know the area, as if they hunted their whole life in this area.

The 21st century equipment, which would require satellites and other stuff that didn't existed in the 12th century doesn't work. So no GPS for example. And, of course, they don't know the area. They DO have a map of the area from our time, but it has most probably change in the last ~900 years. For example the water sources moved etc.

All 100 persons are on top of their hunter efficiency and, of course, trained archers. Just assume they are the best of the world at their respective time. All of them have a basic grip on surviving for multiple days in the wild.
All 50 people coming from the same age work as a team.

All of them know, that they are in some kind of deathmatch. They can only leave the area, if all 50 persons of the other century are dead. After 28 days of "fight", all of them are going to die. It has to be settled until then.

All of them speak the same language, so no problems in this regard.

Everything above in short:

The 12th century guys know the area perfectly, while the 21st century guys (probably) have better, more modern equipment.

Here's my question: which side would be more likely to survive / kill the other?

Don't think about the number of arrows, just assume all of them have access to more than they can use.

Edit (because asked in the comments):

The 50 people were chosen based on being the most efficient for the task of killing the others. So, there are different types of people. For example: Hunters, which just hunted all their life in order to feed their families, as well as soldiers, which even have fought in medieval warfares.

At the start of the deathmatch, all 100 persons "spawn" randomly inside the area. The teams do NOT start as a group at one point.
Thus, while the 12th c. guys perfectly know the area and can immediately search good places to hide and start to hunt the 21st c. guys down, they - the 21st guys - do not know the area (besides their map, which they haven't studied yet).

Comment: In hand to hand combat the 12th century archers have a huge advantage as they tend to have more muscle mass. Modern bows have a low comparative draw weight. Also are these 12th century archers purely hunters/paesants or skilled military bowmen? Very different skillset and tools.

Comment: @Mormacil - "purely hunters or skilled military bowmen" - well, both I'd say. These 50 people are chosen to form the best possible team, so I would say if the skills of both are useful or even required, then both are present.

Comment: Are those guys from 21 century ready to kill? do they have proper mental state or combat experience, survival experience? I would say that special forces guys with bows will totally punish those from 12th century, especially if they have their equip.

Comment: How many tigers are in the forest? Bears? Jaguars? Is this a 21st century European forest, or a primeval 12th century old growth forest? And how do so many people hope to survive more than a few days on the resources of 2 square kilometers of forest?

Comment: @MolbOrg - yes, they do. All of them. They are chosen, because they, as a team, have the highest chance of "winning" this. And while the special forces guys have better equip, the 12th century guys know the area. So multiple special forces guys want even be able to draw their weapons.

Comment: @AlexP - imagine the forest to be perfectly made for this situation. There are resources pretty much everywhere and I would imagine for a lot of people to die in a relative short amount of time.

Comment: so those both groups are pre-selected - let's say by some world match in both times and work as groups. hm, hard to tell then. I would say 40/60 in favor of 21's

Comment: "other stuff that didn't existed in the 12th century doesn't work." does that include radio(Walkie-talkie)?

Comment: @MolbOrg - Everything that works just by itself is fine. Everything that relies on other constructions bigger than something they can carry, won't work.

Comment: ok then 21, 100%. Proper armor, medicine, coordination, night vision, more skilled in tactics especially as teams. Bows are irrelevant in the question, they do not decide in woods too much.

Comment: I just noticed, that I've forgotten to wrote something pretty essential, sorry! At the start of the deathmatch, they all "spawn" completely random inside the area. So while the 21st guys have to coordinate themself, the 12th guys can immediately start to hunt the others down. Non of them knows the coordinates of others at the beginning. I'll edit it into the question above.

Comment: The fact the local know the area and the newcomers do not is the biggest factor, you can kill modern gun wielding soldiers with rocks if you know the terrain and they don't. The bow may never get used.

Comment: I bet on the shark.

Comment: Here is a situation, who would win?  That’s not about **worldbuilding** in any sense.

Comment: @Mormacil the draw weight is not a real advantage, it means they cannot hold their shot. in terms of fps of the projectile (IBO) modern compound bows beat even the best longbows. The average compound falls in the 230 fps range which only the best modern composite longbows can manage, compounds above 300 are available. Mechanical advantage from cams and longer draw length really help.

Comment: Neither side would win. They're find some poison berries and threaten to all kill themselves rather then kill each other for sport. Then a bunch of sequels will spoil this inspirational moment. Either that or the 12th century guys would win because no one today knows what the hell a "inflictint" is.

Comment: It depends on the engagement range.  If the 21st century guys can hold the range open they win as their arrows go further and more accurately.  If the range is close the 12th century guys will likely prevail.

Comment: @John I meant purely as physical training. THe heavier draw weight would give them a more muscular torso, hence advnatage in hand to hand combat compared to modern hunters. But if we're adding special forces nevermind...

Comment: @Mormacil It might not make them any stronger either, remember modern archers will be larger and healthier due to better nutrition and sanitation.

Comment: Modern archers should be better... but would be disqualified after dope test...